# Changing the value of an element of an list within a list Kotlin error

Tags: kotlin

I have

`var layout = mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()`
and I am trying to replace the element

`layout[pr][pc] = 0`

For:

`pr = 1 and pc = 2`

I got `[[-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1]]`

Instead of

`[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]`

Comment: I changed to List MutableList. 
For ```pr = 1 and pc = 2```

I got ```[[-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1]]``` instead of

```[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]```

Comment: @NicoleFoster looks like your external list is holding 4 references to the same object. How do you fill it with inner lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @kabanus mentioned, the inner list is not mutable. If you really want it mutable you can define it like,

```
var layout = mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()
```

Comment: I changed to List MutableList. 

```pr = 1 and pc = 2```

I got ```[[-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1]]``` instead of

```[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`layout[pr].toMutableList()[pc] = 0`

Comment: That will compile, but won't do what OP wants, which is to change the contents of `layout`.  (Instead, it takes a copy of one of its elements, and changes the copy, but then forgets about the copy.)